# Connection from DB client tool (Datagrip) to Vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I am having trouble connecting to Vagrant from the DB client tool (Datagrip).
If you know anything about this, we would appreciate it if you could let us know.

#### connection information

```
→  vagrant ssh-config
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User bargee
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/〇〇/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

#### SSH Connection with Terminal

```
$ ssh bargee@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 -i /Users/〇〇/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
Welcome to Barge 2.15.0, Docker version 20.10.8, build 75249d8
[bargee@barge app]$
```

I was able to do it.

#### ssh connection on Datagrip

[image]

↓

[image]

Unable to connect.

#### Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ailispaw/barge"
  config.vm.box_version = "2.15.0"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/app"
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.gui = false
    vb.cpus = 4
    vb.memory = 4096
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--natdnsproxy1', 'off']
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--natdnshostresolver1', 'off']
  end
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    /etc/init.d/docker restart v20.10.8
    wget "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.6.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -O /opt/bin/docker-compose
    chmod +x /opt/bin/docker-compose
    if ! grep -q "cd /app" /home/bargee/.bashrc ; then 
      echo "cd /app" >> /home/bargee/.bashrc 
    fi
  SHELL
end
```